# Cloud Datastore API - php - GqlQuery - Binding args

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I'm trying to bind some arguments to my GQL query string.
Everything's fine when I run the query without binding anything:

> $result = $DB->query_entities("SELECT * FROM kind WHERE fieldName = 4
>   LIMIT 1");

But I don't know how to bind some arguments. This is how I'm trying to do so:

```
function query_entities($query_string, $args=[]){       
    $gql_query = new Google_Service_Datastore_GqlQuery();
    $gql_query->setQueryString($query_string);
    $gql_query->setAllowLiteral(true);

    if( !empty($args) ){
        $binding_args = [];

        foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
            $binding_value = new Google_Service_Datastore_Value();
            $binding_value->setIntegerValue($value);

            $arg = new Google_Service_Datastore_GqlQueryArg();
            $arg->setName($key);
            $arg->setValue($binding_value);

            $binding_args[] = $arg;
        }

        $gql_query->setNameArgs($binding_args);
    }

        $req = new Google_Service_Datastore_RunQueryRequest();
        $req->setGqlQuery($gql_query);

        return $this->dataset->runQuery($this->dataset_id, $req, []);
}

$exampleValue = 4;

$result = $DB->query_entities("SELECT * FROM kind WHERE fieldName = :fieldName LIMIT 1", ["fieldName" => $exampleValue]);
```

Or:

```
function query_entities($query_string, $args=[]){       
    $gql_query = new Google_Service_Datastore_GqlQuery();
    $gql_query->setQueryString($query_string);
    $gql_query->setAllowLiteral(true);

    if( !empty($args) ){
        $binding_args = [];

        foreach ($args as $value) {
            $binding_value = new Google_Service_Datastore_Value();
            $binding_value->setIntegerValue($value);

            $arg = new Google_Service_Datastore_GqlQueryArg();
            $arg->setValue($binding_value);

            $binding_args[] = $arg;
        }

        $gql_query->setNumberArgs($binding_args);
    }

        $req = new Google_Service_Datastore_RunQueryRequest();
        $req->setGqlQuery($gql_query);

        return $this->dataset->runQuery($this->dataset_id, $req, []);
}

$exampleValue = 4;

$result = $DB->query_entities("SELECT * FROM kind WHERE fieldName = :1 LIMIT 1", [$exampleValue]);
```

This is what I get:
'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/age-of-deployment/runQuery: (400) Lexical error at line 1, column 52. Encountered: ":" (58), after : ""' in ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cloud Datastore GQL](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/gql) and [Python GQL (App Engine)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference) handle argument binding slightly differently.

In this case, you need to use a `@` instead of a `:`, for instance:

```
SELECT * FROM kind WHERE fieldName = @fieldName LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM kind WHERE fieldName = @1 LIMIT 1
```

Here's the [reference documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/gql#argument_binding) for argument binding in Cloud Datastore GQL.

Comment: I could only got the @1 work. @fieldName doesn't work. I don't how to get it work. I've already got my answer, but it would be really great if you could explain how I can pass arguments by name (@fieldName).

Comment: What's the error message you're seeing with the named arguments? Can you confirm that the value of $key in your above example is "fieldName"?

Comment: 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/age-of-deployment/runQuery: (400) A numbered GQL query argument has a name.' in C:\Users\Behnam\Documents\AgeOfDeployment\Backend\Google\Http\REST.php:79 Stack trace: #0

Comment: Yeah, I'm using exactly the same name for $key as I used after @ which means $DB->query_entities("SELECT * FROM kind WHERE fieldName = @fieldName LIMIT 1", ["fieldName" => $exampleValue]);

Comment: The error message indicates that a name was set on a query argument that was then used as a number arg (e.g. using setName() and then setNumerArgs()). However, I don't see that happening in the code you posted above. Can you try printing out the Google_Service_Datastore_GqlQuery object to confirm?

Comment: My bad! I forgot to do setNameArgs() and I was still using setNumerArgs() after using setName() and binding the $keys.